# Max(String) Returns what value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a doubt in MS-SQL Server.

```
Select   Name, max(Class),min(Rank)
from     table t with (nolock)
group by Name
```

Will the above query returns the value containing max(Ascii(Class))

```
Select   Name,max(Ascii(Class)),min(Rank) 
from     table t with (nolock)
group by Name
```

or in the following way

```
Select   Name,max(cast(Class as varbinary)),min(Rank) 
from     table t with (nolock)
group by Name
```

Is this how SQL Server treats them and returns the values...Can anyone tell me the right way the SQL Server treats

Comment: `Class` is what datatype

Comment: Do you have Class in varchar?

Comment: it will display class in descending  order starting from 'Z' will come first

Comment: I think you have seen the question, I am not asking what it returns everyone knows that. I jst want to know how it returns..

Comment: I don't know if this will help but why wouldn't you just write "Select top 1" and order by the string?

Comment: Dude u know well ascii only accepts one character.. whether u r passing @ string also it will take only one thing.. Thats how sql server has designed yet now???

Comment: Perfect dude that even if u r giving ascii(string) it returns first characer ascii, my question is how sql server is treating the first query.. whether it is like in second query or first query or something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup>. A server has a default collation, a database has a default collation, string columns have a collation, and you can override a collation during a particular query.

So,

```
declare @t table (
    Col varchar(50) not null
)
insert into @t(Col) values ('s'),('t'),('ß')

select
    MAX(col collate Latin1_General_CS_AS),
    MAX(col collate Latin1_General_100_BIN)
from @t
```

Returns:

```
-------- --------
t        ß
```

Which result you would get without the [`COLLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184391.aspx) casts depends on what collation the `Class` column has. That would be set when that column was created, either explicitly or by inheriting whatever the database default was at the time of creation.

---

<sup>1</sup>Basically, collations let *you* tell SQL Server what sort order and comparison rules should be used for your particular data, and so `MAX` is just applying the rules that have been selected.

Comment: Thank you Damien, for clearing my doubt and finally it is collation not any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MAX(Class)` would returns string  which comes first in desc order..

Means u have ttt,tuv,tav means result would be tuv

But `SELECT MAX(Ascii(Class))` return first ascii value of the first character in the string dude....

In SELECT max(cast(Class as varbinary)) also work like SELECT MAX(Class) query...

Comment: I jst need one confirmation like how will SQL internally process the statement. Like it will convert all values to what(Varbinary or binary) for better understanding by the computer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select   Name, max(Class),min(Rank)
from     table t with (nolock)
group by Name
```

This will return `Alphabetically top 1 from descending order`

```
Select   Name,max(Ascii(Class)),min(Rank) 
from     table t with (nolock)
group by Name
```

This one take the `first letter's ASCII value` from all rows and return the MAX value. For e.g. Class is "End", the ASCII value of 'E' is '69'.

Comment: I already told that Jesuraja, y not second one you can simply add a comment for that..

Comment: How I can put this many lines in Comment... This is easy to read